# Angularjs URL in default value in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set the default value via ng-model in a textarea.
The content came from JSON

it would be something like this

```
$scope.message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, provident!\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, provident! http://drive.google.com/";
```

But it become blank in the textarea:

```
    <ion-view title="Tab Title">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate><textarea type="text" class="textarea" placeholder="" ng-model="message" ng-maxlength="150" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" ng-bind-html="message"></textarea>
<div ng-hide="feedback === 1">
            <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="activate()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || sendingData">
                    <i class="ion-alert-circled"></i> Go
            </button>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Anyway to get around this?

btw, I'm doing the app with ionic framework.

Comment: It's working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/7bwa3E7LFN76YmCZcHao?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, it works on your demo. Does it has something to do with $scope when I get the data async with promise?!

Comment: OK I created another one which doesn't work
what's wrong with $http here?
[link]http://plnkr.co/edit/CuynVsy5mKJUycDPP2C9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is very easy. There are 2 bugs in your plunker:

1. Your json file is invalid, remove the `';'` at the end to make it valid json.
2. The text you try to set on the field is just too long! You could either remove the `ng-maxlength`, or leave it just as `maxlength`.

Sad that there is no warning or error from Angular at all when trying to set a too long text on a textfield with maxlength defined..

Comment: Doh! You are right about the ng-maxlength & the semi-colon. How silly I am! Thanks for catching this!